# Zoom Move Pinch listener in google maps v2 in android

Tags: android, gesture, android-maps-v2

i'm using the **maps v2** in my Android APP

My map is automatically updated every few seconds to show some new points on the map.
For every time it refresh, automatically the following event: "setOnCameraChangeListener" is called.

The user can interact with the map by moving the camera or doing the Zoom. I need to intercept the user's gesture on the map such as "Zoom", "Drag", the "Pinch Open" or "Pinch Close".

So I can not use the "OnCameraChangeListener" because this is already done automatically from application when it auto update the data, and I am not able to understand when the event occurs for an automatic update of the map or when by user interaction

How do I trap these this user gesture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> automatically the following event: "setOnCameraChangeListener" is called.

Nothing is done automatically.

> updated every few seconds to show some new points on the map.

and:

> Then readjust the Zoom to fit the actual Marker on the map.

This seems like a very bad user experience: forcing user to look at your marker when they just want to swipe to Africa.

Anyway, if you have `GoogleMap.animateCamera` call in your code, you may use `CancelableCallback` parameter to help you distinguish between user activity and code call resulting in `onCameraChange`. [See this comment on gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4636#c21) for how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call whatever you do after the auto-update in the code block that handles the auto update, and not in the `OnCameraChangeListener`. Then use the `OnCameraChangeListener` to do actions that should be done only when the camera actually moves (whether it is caused by the user or by your code).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately I can not do as you say.

When the map is automatically updated it draw some new marker, or it takes away some existing. Then readjust the Zoom to fit the actual Marker on the map. This thing is needed for the project.
Fit the Zoom for new Marker call the "OnCameraChangeListener" event automatically, and so I can not follow your advice.